# Unable to download large files from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, firefox, download

I am trying to download two files originally linked on [this page](http://poliigon.helpscoutdocs.com/article/29-how-to-use-poliigon-in-blender). The author has edited the linked page but an archived version of the page and files I was referring to can be [found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614071755/http://poliigon.helpscoutdocs.com/article/29-how-to-use-poliigon-in-blender). The links are right beneath the text **Downloads from the video**:

> Downloads from the video:
>
> [Start.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PFSrI9B3iwY3lfaWRJUXNmQms/view?usp=sharing)
>   [Finished.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PFSrI9B3iwWnd5dElDN0k0ZVE)
>   [Normal Map Combine.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PFSrI9B3iwaGJFUjlndnZQVzA) - Simple Node group to combine any normal map together.

I'm using the latest version of Firefox. The files in question are hosted on Google Drive, and have 64MB and 135 MB, respectively. I am trying to download them one by one, as that is the way they are hosted.

Google warns that it's unable to scan either of the files due to their size. I click on **Download anyway**, and the page reloads. Regardless of how many times I try this, the page just keeps reloading every time, and download doesn't start.

This behaviour persists in both normal and private mode. I've also tried using Opera, and the behaviour was the same.

Googling about gave back [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/doaoaxXuqjQ), so I guess I'm not the only one with the problem, and it seems the issue is not new.

Does anyone know how I can download the two files by using Firefox?

Comment: Which links point to the files that you are trying to download?

Comment: @Rubén It seems that the author has changed the file's host. It used to be Google Drive, but now is Amazon AWS. Original question edited.

Comment: I was able to download the 64MB using the lasted version of Firefox for Windows. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: @Rubén - I've somehow missed your question originally. Apologies for answering this late. I managed to solve the problem by setting my Windows time to be the correct time / synchronized with Microsoft's server (it was set to be 40min ahead of current time, due to my personal preferences).

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any issue for Google Drive downloads.
**Try on different network connection.**

Note: Use updated version of Browser

Comment: I have no other connection on which I could try. I am already using the latest version of Firefox, as stated in the original question.

Comment: I tried those file on my network, it's works perfectly for me

Comment: Hm, it's still not working for me, even after resetting my router, and obtaining a different IP address. Perhaps it is a network / ISP related issue, but the same thing happens if I try to access the file via Tor, or any of the webproxies. And it seems that it's not a browser thing, since the problem occurs in both Firefox and Opera.The more I try, the less it becomes about actually getting the file, and more about discovering why this happens. Thank you for still taking an interest in this.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.
Solution for me was changing time zone in windows settings.
Reason: cookie started with "download_warning_....", returned from google.com, become immediately expired and never sent back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I was having the issue in a VM with guest additions installed, which was screwing up the clock and making the download fail.

Comment: @Myles That's it! It was a clock issue with me - I've set my computer's time to 40min ahead of real time (so that I wouldn't be late when I'm supposed to go anywhere, I do the same with the wristwatch and all the other watches and clocks around the house). That's what was messing things up in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not a network issue, for me it's not: I'm using two different pcs on the same connection, with different o.s. (XP & Win7) and different antivirus protection, the XP one it's able to download, the other not (same files), in the same way described by FiddlingAway. The page recharge with a little address'difference in the string preceding the file id.

Comment: It turned out to be a time / clock related issue. If Windows time is not in sync with the set timezone, this issue happens. Once I reset my clock to the correct time and timezone, everything turned out well.

Answer (score 0):

Mac and Windows user might try to use Google Drive for Desktop.  Once it's installed, using Finder / Windows Explorer locate the file and set it to be available offline.